# Some Models permission are missing from the permission list in django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-permissions

Account models has lot of the models but only the user models permission are visible
[image]

These are some of the models of out lot of models in the file for which permission are not visible

```
class Child(TimeStampedModel):
    child_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    profile_image = models.URLField(null=True)
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    school_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    field_of_interest = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200), default=list)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    contest_qualification_level = models.ForeignKey(ContestQualificationLevel, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,related_name='child_contest_qualification_level')
    contest_scope = models.ForeignKey(ContestScope, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    hold_contest_qualification_level = models.ForeignKey(ContestQualificationLevel, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='child_hold_contest_qualification_level')
    teacher_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    teacher_mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)

class Agent(TimeStampedModel):
    agent_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class UserSubscriptionLogs(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subscription = models.ForeignKey('order.Subscription', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount_paid = models.FloatField(default=0)
    currency_code = models.CharField(max_length=5)
```

Comment: Can you share a model that has no permissions set. Did you run migrations for these new models?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Sure edited the answer, I didn't paste all of them just some of them. Also I have just run the migrate command on the database migration files are already there.